# Maven shade twice - how to define jar to shade

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

In my build process, I need to shade twice. Why I do this is not really relevant to the question, but here is the reason: because I first shade my own dependencies, then I obfuscate this first fat jar, and then I want to shade the third party dependencies too.

Firs difficulty was to have the goals run in the correct order. By default, if everything happens at the packaging phase (which would seem rather logical) both shades are performed in a row, and obfuscation is performed afterwards. I managed to tweak the maven phases so the goals execute in the correct order, but now I am stuck, because it seems that:

- the first shade performs automatically on the output of my
  `maven-jar-plugin`
- the second shade does the same

Thus I end up with one obfuscated partially-shaded jar, and one fully-shaded not obfuscated jar.

I could not find relevant option to force a particular source jar to the shade configuration. [Shade documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) does not give clues. I suppose I may solve my problem by performing everything in place but I had rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a brief scan of the [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-shade-plugin/blob/maven-shade-plugin-3.2.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/shade/mojo/ShadeMojo.java) and indeed, it doesn't look like it's possible to specify the input jar in the configuration, as of plugin version 3.2.1. The error message around line 550 specifically mentions a requirement on the jar from the `jar` plugin. There are some [open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-154) [issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-304) that seem to be requesting something similar.

After checking the docs though, I wonder if you could configure things to keep overwriting the main jar (`target/my-artifact-1.0.0.jar`). In other words, configure both the first shade execution and the obfuscation to direct output to that file. Then, the second shade execution will have the right input. The downside to this approach is there will be no intermediate files to analyze if something goes wrong.

Perhaps writing a custom transformer as suggested in the comments to [MSHADE-304](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-304) is a better idea for this case.

Comment: Following your advice, I ended up overwriting, but it was a bit trickier because shade cannot overwrite. (I got "error : cannot open jar" or similar). So the solution was to configure _the obfuscator_ to overwrite the initial jar. So the actual sequence of jars is: initial => shaded1 => initial => shaded2 (final).
This works. It is a pity no other solution is offered by the tool. Writing a custom transformer seems overkill for such a trivial need.